COUNT_NWNE_P10 & COUNT_WNE_P10 appear to be swapped
The fields COUNT_NWNE_P10 – Not working 10 years after entry versus COUNT_WNE_P10 –Working 10 years after entry appear to be swapped in the latest 'Most-Recent-Cohorts-Institution' file.
In prior years, the numbers working have been much larger than the numbers not working for each institution. In this year's Most-Recent-Cohorts-Institution file, the figures appear to be swapped. Institutions that typically show around 90% of students working (if both metrics are added together and the number working is divided into the whole) are showing 10%. Can you confirm?
